# FPDF - combined font styles

Tags: php, fpdf

By using FPDF (multiCell) I'm not able to apply different tags for a simple word.

As an example:

```
<em><strong><u>Sample</u></strong></em>
```

At the end it's shown in PDF only with underscore style (latest one). Is there any possibilities to combine them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you're using [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) or [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/) since FPDF'`Multicell` function doesn't seem to accept HTML, but with TCPDF an HTML string with multiples tags works:

```
$ishtml = true;
$test = '<em><strong><u>Sample</u></strong></em>';
$pdf->MultiCell($width, $height, $test, $border, '$align, $fill, $ln, $x, $y, $reseth, $stretch, $ishtml);
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like we have to use TCPDF.

Answer (score 1):

if you still want to use FPDF, you can write any HTML tags by using a simple functions like this below

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF_HTML extends FPDF
{
    var $B=0;
    var $I=0;
    var $U=0;
    var $HREF='';
    var $ALIGN='';

    function WriteHTML($html)
    {
        //HTML parser
        $html=str_replace("\n",' ',$html);
        $a=preg_split('/<(.*)>/U',$html,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
        foreach($a as $i=>$e)
        {
            if($i%2==0)
            {
                //Text
                if($this->HREF)
                    $this->PutLink($this->HREF,$e);
                elseif($this->ALIGN=='center')
                    $this->Cell(0,5,$e,0,1,'C');
                else
                    $this->Write(5,$e);
            }
            else
            {
                //Tag
                if($e[0]=='/')
                    $this->CloseTag(strtoupper(substr($e,1)));
                else
                {
                    //Extract properties
                    $a2=explode(' ',$e);
                    $tag=strtoupper(array_shift($a2));
                    $prop=array();
                    foreach($a2 as $v)
                    {
                        if(preg_match('/([^=]*)=["\']?([^"\']*)/',$v,$a3))
                            $prop[strtoupper($a3[1])]=$a3[2];
                    }
                    $this->OpenTag($tag,$prop);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function OpenTag($tag,$prop)
    {
        //Opening tag
        if($tag=='B' || $tag=='I' || $tag=='U')
            $this->SetStyle($tag,true);
        if($tag=='A')
            $this->HREF=$prop['HREF'];
        if($tag=='BR')
            $this->Ln(5);
        if($tag=='P')
            $this->ALIGN=$prop['ALIGN'];
        if($tag=='HR')
        {
            if( !empty($prop['WIDTH']) )
                $Width = $prop['WIDTH'];
            else
                $Width = $this->w - $this->lMargin-$this->rMargin;
            $this->Ln(2);
            $x = $this->GetX();
            $y = $this->GetY();
            $this->SetLineWidth(0.4);
            $this->Line($x,$y,$x+$Width,$y);
            $this->SetLineWidth(0.2);
            $this->Ln(2);
        }
    }

    function CloseTag($tag)
    {
        //Closing tag
        if($tag=='B' || $tag=='I' || $tag=='U')
            $this->SetStyle($tag,false);
        if($tag=='A')
            $this->HREF='';
        if($tag=='P')
            $this->ALIGN='';
    }

    function SetStyle($tag,$enable)
    {
        //Modify style and select corresponding font
        $this->$tag+=($enable ? 1 : -1);
        $style='';
        foreach(array('B','I','U') as $s)
            if($this->$s>0)
                $style.=$s;
        $this->SetFont('',$style);
    }

    function PutLink($URL,$txt)
    {
        //Put a hyperlink
        $this->SetTextColor(0,0,255);
        $this->SetStyle('U',true);
        $this->Write(5,$txt,$URL);
        $this->SetStyle('U',false);
        $this->SetTextColor(0);
    }
}
?>
```

and you just write your HTML code by call that function, like this

```
<?php
require('WriteHTML.php');

$pdf=new PDF_HTML();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial');
$pdf->WriteHTML('You can<br><p align="center">center a line</p>and add a horizontal rule:<br><hr>');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

See [this HTML sample by FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script41.php) and [here the result](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/ex41.pdf)

Hope it can help you and the others